# What are the differences between 效果 and 结果?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

效果和结果有什么区别？Can both be used in the same context as synonyms, or are there situations in which one fits better than the other?
谢谢。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Chinese American, These two words indeed have the same meaning. let me think about it and describe it to you in the best way. See that help.

**结果(result/outcome)** = The final outcome of the development of something."结果" is the effect of subjective actions, and also refers to the outcome of the development and changes of objective things, which can be good or bad. "结果" does represent the final of something.

1.例子: 这一场的比赛胜负结果已经出来了。(Example: The outcome of this game has been announced)
2.例子:我的期中考试的结果出来了, 我得到了100分。 (Example:The results of my midterm exam are in, and I got a 100)

**效果(effect/effectiveness)** = Unknown/know result of some behavior/experiment. "效果"Focuses on referring to the result. "效果" does not have to represent the final of something.

1.例子: 那种新药试验效果不错。(Example:That new drug was tested well.)
2.例子:广播剧中那场战斗的音响效果很好。(Example:The audio for that battle in the radio play is great)

Lastly, I would like to say, it is depended on our artistic conception at that time. Sometimes we use the only ones that can't exchange them for another, When describe how good is the reflection of a mirror example:反光的效果(reflective effect), so is not 反光的结果(reflective result).

Answer (score 3):

效果 = **effect** --> result (of an intervention)

结果 = (end/ final) **result**

- 结果 is **the end** result
- 效果 means effect, which is **a** result

Example:

他不戒菸的**結果**是患上肺癌 - The **result** of his failure to quit smoking was he getting lung cancer

化疗的**效果**十分有限  - The **effect** of chemotherapy is very limited

Answer (score 1):

Tricky! A hard and fast rule will not be forthcoming I think!

效果：产生的结果

Seems 结果  is more, though not entirely, stand-alone, whereas  效果 is more the result of something (什么东西的效果）.

**结果**，服务被大大减少了。
As a result, services have been drastically reduced.

她对**这个结果**感到高兴。
She was delighted at the result.

她对这次使用的**药的效果**感到满意。
She was satisfied with the results/effect of the medicine used this time.